# JRE throws an exception and glassfish is terminated at windows 64 bit machine

Tags: java, netbeans, glassfish, vaadin, jrebel

I've JDK 1.8 and using NetBeans IDE 8.0 to develop my vaadin 7.5.3 application. No idea whats causing this exception.

**Detail of the Exception**

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000000006fc26a6b, pid=6200, tid=12848
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0-b132) (build 1.8.0-b132)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.0-b70 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [jvm.dll+0x2b6a6b]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\Program Files\glassfish-4.0\glassfish\domains\domain1\config\hs_err_pid6200.log
Compiled method (c1) 1102730  563       2       java.lang.NullPointerException::<init> (5 bytes)
 total in heap  [0x0000000002dc4290,0x0000000002dc4600] = 880
 relocation     [0x0000000002dc43b0,0x0000000002dc43e8] = 56
 main code      [0x0000000002dc4400,0x0000000002dc44c0] = 192
 stub code      [0x0000000002dc44c0,0x0000000002dc4568] = 168
 metadata       [0x0000000002dc4568,0x0000000002dc4588] = 32
 scopes data    [0x0000000002dc4588,0x0000000002dc45b0] = 40
 scopes pcs     [0x0000000002dc45b0,0x0000000002dc45f0] = 64
 dependencies   [0x0000000002dc45f0,0x0000000002dc4600] = 16
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=192m; support was removed in 8.0
```

**Update**

here is hs_err_pid6200.log file http://pastebin.com/RNGkvvtQ

And I'm using jRebel and xrebel

here is my JVM options:
[image: JVM Options]

Comment: Do you get this when you start Glassfish or when you deploy your application ?
Can you give the JVM arguments of Glassfish that are in the log in Netbeans when it starts ?

Comment: Can you show us the contents of hs_err_pid6200.log ?

Comment: @Priyanshu I have pasted the hs_err_pid6200.log file in this http://pastebin.com/RNGkvvtQ

Comment: @rjdkolb I'm getting this after some times after the application has started

Comment: Is the exception thrown only when JRebel/XRebel are enabled, or is the glassfish terminating even without these tools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the Xrebel trial period was over and apparently the glassfish server start crashing often after tht, I've removed the `xrebel` from my JVM options and currently there is no JRE exception So I think the problem was with the out dated `Xrebel`. hope this helps someone

[image]